# Shell aws cli validate elastic ip if exits

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services

I am creating a script in shell bash to validate if an ip elastica exists, but I cannot save the error message that the console returns in a variable.

I try with:

```
aws ec2 describe-addresses --region us-west-2 --public-ips 44.239.43.37 --output text --query 'Addresses[*].AllocationId' | grep "not found" | wc -l
```

amazon console returns the following message:

```
An error occurred (InvalidAddress.NotFound) when calling the DescribeAddresses operation: Address '44.239.43.37' not found.
```

How can I capture the message from the console to use it through a condition so I can validate if the ip exists or does not exist?

EDIT:

I tried this

```
ELASTICIP_INFO=`aws ec2 describe-addresses --public-ips $IP_EC2 | jq -r '.Addresses[].AllocationId' 2>&1 | grep "not found" | wc -l`

if [ "$?" -ne "1" ];
then
    echo -e "\x1B[01;34m IP Not Found \x1B[0m"
    exit 0
fi
```

not working continue printing error message:

```
An error occurred (InvalidAddress.NotFound) when calling the DescribeAddresses operation: Address '52.2.132.235' not found.
 IP not found
```

Regards,

Comment: The error message is output to *stderr*, not *stdout*, so you need to redirect *stderr* in order to capture the output in your pipeline: `aws ... 2>&1 | grep "not found" | wc -l`

Comment: hello, I updated the case I keep getting an error.

Comment: You need to redirect the output of the `aws` command, not the `jq` command.